# member reference base type 'double [10]' is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, root

I created a fixed array `e_pt[10]` initialised with zeros. I then filled in some values into the array `e_pt`. I would then like to find the index of the largest element in the array. The code is shown below.

```cpp
double e_pt[10] = {};

for (size_t lep_i=0; lep_i<lep_n; lep_i++) // loop over leptons
{
    if (lep_type->at(lep_i) == 11)   // record kinematic info of electrons into array
    {
        e_pt[lep_i] = lep_pt->at(lep_i); 
    }

} // end of loop over leptons       

int e_index = std::distance(e_pt.begin(), std::max_element(e_pt.begin(), e_pt.end()));
```

However when I try to compile this, the following error occurs:

> member reference base type 'double [10]' is not a structure or union

It is refering to the action  e_pt.begin() being invalid.

What is wrong here?

Comment: it is a C++ file used for a physics root project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::max_element(e_pt.begin(), e_pt.end())` Native array doesn't have methods like that.

It should be

```
std::max_element(std::begin(e_pt), std::end(e_pt));
```

This error relates to use of . operator on array. Your loop can be simpler, if `lep_n` is size of `lep_pt` and `lep_pt` is  container compatible with C++ ranges.

```
size_t lep_i = 0;
for (auto pt : lep_pt)
  if (lep_type->at(lep_i) == 11)   
    e_pt [lep_i++] = pt;
```

Or vice versa relative to `lep_type`.